# Entity Framework Code First Deleting By ID Without Fetching (Generic Style)

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Please tell me if this is a decent approach to deleting an Entity without fetching it given I have the ID.

I have a generic store with the following interface (I'll only show Delete):

```
public interface IStore : IReadOnlyStore
{
    void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity, new();
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

And in the concrete Store class of that interface, here's my delete method:

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{
     var obj = Ctx.Entry(entity);
     if (obj.State ==  System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
     {
         Ctx.Set(typeof(TEntity)).Attach(obj.Entity);
     }
     Ctx.Set(typeof(TEntity)).Remove(obj.Entity);
}
```

I have tested both newing up an Entity:

```
Store.Delete(new Foo() { Id = request.Entity.Id });
```

as well as fetching an entity and then calling delete.

Through debugging, I have the desired affect on both scenarios.

I just want to make sure this is a good design and that there are no side effects to this approach.

For reference, Ctx is just the DbContext itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good design and doesn't have side effects :) (IMHO)

Two remarks:

- I'm wondering if you could simplify your `Delete` method by:

  ```
  public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
      where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
  {
      Ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
  }
  ```

  I would hope that setting the state to `Deleted` will attach automatically if the entity isn't already attached. But I am not sure if it works. (Let me know whether it works for attached and detached scenarios (if you should test this).)
- If you have performance optimization in mind (avoiding to load the entities) don't forget that, if there are multiple entities to delete in the context, `SaveChanges` will still send one single DELETE statement per entity to the database. Bulk deletes with EF are quite terrible in performance and it's a terrain where going back to a SQL statements (DELETE ... WHERE ... IN ... many IDs....) sometimes makes sense (if performance matters).

Comment: Thanks for yoru feedback. I tried your suggestion, but it killed more than 50% of my unit tests. The common error seems to be:  An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.

Comment: See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: A relationship from the 'Foo_Siblings' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Foo_Siblings_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.